# Translating monad composition to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, scala, h2

I'm working on a language integrated query library in Scala (http://github.com/getquill/quill) and there's one type of monad composition that I'm struggling to generate the correspondent SQL query for.

It's possible to generate queries for these cases:

```
t1.flatMap(a => t2.filter(b => b.s == a.s).map(b => b.s))

   SELECT t2.s FROM t1, t2 WHERE t2.s = t1.s

t1.flatMap(a => t2.map(b => b.s).take(10))

   SELECT x.s FROM t1, (SELECT * FROM t2 LIMIT 10) x
```

But I can't figure out how to express this other one:

```
t1.flatMap(a => t2.filter(b => b.s == a.s).map(b => b.s).take(10))
```

Is it possible? The question also could be phrased as: is there a way to express this kind of data dependency in monadic compositions using applicative joins in SQL?

I'm looking for a generic solution so it could be used for other compositions like these ones:

```
t1.flatMap(a => t2.filter(b => b.s == a.s).sortBy(b => b.s % a.s).map(b => b.s).take(10))
t1.flatMap(a => t2.filter(b => b.s == a.s).map(b => b.s).take(10).flatMap(b => t3.filter(c => c.s == b.s/a.s))
```

I'm working on dialects for MySQL, Postgres and H2.

Comment: You might want to take a look at how they do it in Slick. Good luck with that though...

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jasper. Slick generates invalid SQL for this kind of composition.

Comment: Can you provide a gist with your monad definition and example?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 the example is in the question description. The monad interface is here: https://github.com/getquill/quill/blob/master/quill-core/src/main/scala/io/getquill/Queryable.scala

Comment: @Edmondo1984 You can also find more information here: https://gist.github.com/fwbrasil/2db2b6ac2b86fe820442

Answer (score 1):

Once you need to filter the inner set, by the existence in the outer you need to push the join down.  Something like this, maybe:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1, (
  SELECT t2.s
  FROM t2, t1 AS t1_inner
  WHERE t1_inner.s = t2.s
  LIMIT 10
)
```

Or, alternatively:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1, (
  SELECT t2.s
  FROM t2
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t1 t1_inner WHERE t1_inner.s = t2.s)
  LIMIT 10
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've just added more information to the question. I'm looking for a general solution that is flexible enough to work for similar compositions.